# Binary operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'Bool' and 'String?' for Swift in 2020

Tags: swift, string, boolean

I can't seem to figure out why the equal operator won't work.

[image: databaseManager.swift pic 1]
[image]

Here's my code:

```
@IBAction func LoginButton(_ sender: UIButton) {

    let Username = UsernameTextField.text;
    let Password = PasswordTextField.text;

    
    //Pull stored data from server
    let usernameStored = shareInstance.database?.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO Signups( Username, Password) VALUES(?,?)", withArgumentsIn: [Username,Password])
    shareInstance.database?.close()
    
    let passwordStored = shareInstance.database?.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO Signups( Username, Password) VALUES(?,?)", withArgumentsIn: [Username,Password])
    shareInstance.database?.close()
    
    if(usernameStored! == Username)
    {
        if(passwordStored! == Password)
        {
            //Login is successful.
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Because of the error that you shared in your title. It looks like `usernameStored` is a `Bool`, probably saying whether or not the executed command was successful. You can't compare that against the `String` value of the username.

You're essentially asking if `true` equals `"johnsmith"`.

Check what the `executeUpdate()` method returns. Read its documentation.

Comment: I see. I thought this shareInstance path was the path to my SQLite database where the username and password can retrieve the login credential. Does this not seem to be the path to use?

Comment: @alexander I see. I thought this shareInstance path was the path to my SQLite database where the username and password can retrieve the login credential. Does this not seem to be the path to use?

Comment: @Jariusb24 Without knowing the framework providing the database functionality, I can't assist further. I don't know how it operates or where the data you're looking for might be.

Comment: No problem. I have found the correct path to the data. Like you brought out earlier, usernameStored keeps converting back to bool. Do you know why this is? I've been tackling this issues for a few days now, so any info would be very helpful!

Comment: @Jariusb24 The reason is that method (.executeUpdate()) is performing the action on the database. So you perform the action, in your case of inserting data into your database, and it is returning a `Bool` saying whether or not the action was successful. That's why it's a `Bool`. It's not returning what it actually entered.

Comment: So there's my issue. I'm trying to retrieve data from the database, not insert data? Which means I need to find the correct path to my database.

Comment: @Jariusb24 Again, I don't know what database framework you're using. But I would look for something that lets you `select` something from your database, or that performs a `fetch` of some kind. You want to read data, not update what is there.

Comment: I'm not sure why I didn't see your reply, but thanks for getting back to me! I've been working with java, but this is my first experience with swift. I'm using an SQLite database. I see what you're saying. I need to find data, not update it. So my path I have listed is the problem. I just need to find the correct path. If it's possible, I can share my project with you. I believe it's in my databaseManager.swift file, but I've tried different paths from here as well and get the same result.

Comment: I've just uploaded the pic of my databaseManager.swift file to the question. I hope this helps. :)

Comment: Thanks. I can see you're using FMDB now. Per the documentation, what you're interested in is probably the `executeQuery(executeQuery:values:)` function, which returns results as a `FMResultSet`. That'll return what you're looking for.

Comment: so it did resolve my binary operator issue, which now makes sense. I'm getting an unresolved identifier error. I don't have an executeQuery command. I just plugged in the function you sent verbatim.

Comment: You need to make a valid SQL query to your SQLite table in that method. I've not used FMDB personally, so I don't know the best way to do it. Nor do I know your full database schema. We're moving away from the original question and more into general programming help. I'd suggest either opening another question, starting a discussion at /r/Swift on Reddit, or, while I can't promise much more help, you can reach out on Twitter to me (same username).